# How describe function on TS for map of class constructors

Tags: typescript

I try to implement function that returns JS Object contained class instance as value and class name as key.

Something like:

```js
const init = (construcorsMap) => {
    return Object.keys(construcorsMap).reduce((ret, constructorName) => {
         ret[constructorName] = new (construcorsMap[constructorName])();
         return ret;
     }, {});

class C1 {};
class C2 {};
const instances = init({C1: C1, C2: C2});
```

How I can notate it on TypeScript?

Comment: Doesn't it should be `public constructor(){ consol.log("code here")}`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: @unional We can model this with what we already have in TS

Comment: Yeah, I miss read the question. I thought he tries to get an array at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `InstanceType` and a custom mapped type. You will need some type assertions in the implementation, but the call site will be fully type safe

```
type InstanceTypes<T extends Record<keyof T, new () => any>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: InstanceType<T[P]>
}
const init = <T extends Record<keyof T, new () => any>>(construcorsMap: T): InstanceTypes<T>  => {
    return (Object.keys(construcorsMap) as Array<keyof T>).reduce((ret, constructorName) => {
        ret[constructorName] = new (construcorsMap[constructorName])();
        return ret;
    }, {} as InstanceTypes<T>);
}

class C1 { c1!: number};
class C2 { c2!: string};
const instances = init({C1: C1, C2: C2});
instances.C1.c1;
instances.C2.c2
```

Live copy [on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgZ2AQzgYwgFXBBAeTKCAD2AjgBMEoAlCNAewCcK8BrCEBgMykwBoocCAHcoACgCUUALwA+KKhByFMqAG8AUFB1QA2gAUoASzhQOXXpgC6ALliIU6LDgKHrczQF9NjRybhjYFkoAiJScipaemZWCx4+QWExKVkFJRVxPyQmAFdGJgQAWWQwe0xJe3gkVAxsSHxMBTSNbV0mCGBcpjNxAHkAIwAremAAOgsELIZHPILi0ulkagBBJiZkEHZOBKbJMY6KfIhxcQ7gQWzgOeBmADlkAFsIaXlW3Q+oc70rm-uniDWELJCS-fLMBZgH4zHL5W5MB7PaySKQAbjany+nW6ZnO6I+XkE6i8imo1ScdRwjTkknRPl8ABtltQAMIARg0UDQbIAhPY4LlHgMIEwvOi0EyEKyAEyctDSvlQHKmADmYt8MOCphqzmoalMQXE6nZ9nZghZ0tN0q8tM02opuDG7LG3PR9tqjotLulQA).

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know `T` can reference `keyof T`. :)

Comment: @unional You can, it's basically a distinct type that has to be inferred so referencing it in `T` is not recursive. Here it's basically the same thing as `PropertyKey`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `InstanceMap` type using the build-in `InstanceType`:

```
type InstanceMap<C extends Record<string, new () => any>> = {
  [k in keyof C]: InstanceType<C[k]>
};

function init<C extends Record<string, new () => any>>(classMap: C): InstanceMap<C> {
  // your implementation
  return {} as any
}

class C1 { foo1() {} }
class C2 { foo2() {} }
const classMap = { C1, C2 };

const instances = init(classMap)
instances.C1.foo1()
instances.C2.foo2()
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgOwM4gIYIMZQLKogHgGEYoAPEKBAEyRgCUoMB7AJyvxRYEsEBzAGhgIoAdxgAKAJQwAvAD4Y6MHIUyYAb2AwYAbQDWMHjD1QwTAGYxCAXQBc8ZGkxQAKpChF91ucAC+AbmBgcwBXTBAuJgRDBC4QIhJyShp6RlZ2Th4BIVEJaXlFBGU5cQwAG1QkJFwIe0JJe0QUdCwaogVNbQB6LpgzEJZDAFsIMqghyjQIqK0YFigQAej1X0VaJT8g8sraQgBGDRhzJiY9qQ1V32BtqqsAJkPjpjvzlZgr5kcYG+q8WUP9nU9oJCHc6g8AlsoigYs1nLQ1Dw4qUKlUapJgDw4VgkAA6fa4p5nDFYpw4-F3QknF4YoA)